# create captive portal with email or facebook authentication

Tags: openwrt, captiveportal, hotspot

I want to create a captive portal , Where users who want to connect to the wireless network (wifi), they are redirected to a webpage . then a form where they have to put email or press like button of facebook to start navigate freely.

I have installed openwrt on my router, What tools do i need? 
how can i let them navigate after the login form??

thanks.

Comment: You can use CoovaChilli, almost everybody in the world uses it for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to install RadiusDesk or, more intersting chillspot [here is](https://www.howtoforge.com/openwrt-chillispot-freeradius-chillifire-hotspots-including-paypal-payment-gateway)